# ASP.NET Core + Amazon SES: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ses, mailkit

I am trying to send email using ASP.NET Core, MailKit and Amazon SES:

```
  using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("smtp.log"))) {
      client.Connect("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
      client.Authenticate("myusername", "mypassword");
      await client.SendAsync(message);
      client.Disconnect(true);
  }
```

I keep getting the error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.".

And the log file shows:

```
Connected to smtp://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587/?starttls=always
S: 220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1737464811 qt5bXhIgVseJaHPspjp4
C: EHLO [127.0.0.1]
S: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-SIZE 10485760
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
S: 250 Ok
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 Ready to start TLS
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide your own `client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` method to verify the server certificate. It can be as simple as always returning true or it can check the fingerprint against a known fingerprint for the server or any number of other possibilities.

For more information, see http://www.mimekit.org/docs/html/P_MailKit_MailService_ServerCertificateValidationCallback.htm